# By American Standards

Tags: mathematics, computer-science

I once went to the USA and a guy asked me,

> "What is a+B?"

I could answer him.

**What was my answer?**

HINT:

> The title is a clue

Note: The title is appropriate, and B is capitalized on purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a+B is

> 163

since

> a is 97 and B is 66, when refered to by their decimal code in the **American Standard** Code for Information Interchange (ASCII) encoding.

Answer (score 6):

a+B equals:

> 974366, using ASCII codes for a(97), +(43) and B(66)

Comment: Well tried. But it is wrong. Why did you concatenate them? and also, why did you add 43?

Comment: It's the ASCII code for '+' and in the USA that's how they think. 9766 would also be valid.

Comment: oh! I myself didn't think of it. I never intended it to be the answer by the way.

Comment: You could have also added the value for the question mark(?)

Comment: I put that in because the statement is a question, and wouldn't have come out in normal speech. I assume he asked you 'What is lower-case A plus upper-case B?', and it is customary to add a question mark to such questions.